# Select Visible Rasters (Mosaic Datasets) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, mosaic-dataset

I am wondering if anyone knows if there is arcpy functionality available in ArcGIS 10.3 or can be coded easily to replicate the select visible rasters command (manually right clicking on a Mosaic Dataset Footprint in the table of contents in an ArcMap session).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is similar: Use [`ListDataFrames()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listdataframes.htm) to get current display extent and then [`MakeMosaicLayer()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-mosaic-layer.htm) to create a temporary mosaic.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]     # grab 1st dataframe in map
#df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Main")[0] # grab dataframe named 'Main'
arcpy.MakeMosaicLayer_management(
    'Orthophotos',  # input mosaic
    'test_mosaic',  # output mosaic
    '#',            # Optional WHERE clause
    df.extent       # clipping box coordinates
    )
```

Sources:

- Geonet: [Getting current visible extent](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/38153)
- Geonet: [Mosaic Dataset - Select Visible Rasters](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/159640)